# Use AutoHotKey to output JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

Can someone explain how to use AutoHotKey to OUTPUT JavaScript when I type a piece of text?  For example, I would like type...

> `iff`

... and have AutoHotKey replace that text with...

> `if (err) { return callback(err); }`

I've tried using Send, quotes, slashes... nothing works.  I've also tried countless Google searches but everything finds people trying to CONTROL AutoHotKey with JavaScript instead of having it OUTPUT JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `::` at beginning and end of some text defines HotString that will do what you need. Also use `SendRaw` instead of `Send` because curly braces are special characters

```
::iff::
   SendRaw,if (err) { return callback(err); }
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptControl Object allows AHk to execute javascript.

```
jSplode(str,del) {
    sc:=ComObjCreate("ScriptControl"),sc.Language:="JScript"
    js:="str='" str "';aR=str.split(""" del """);",sc.ExecuteStatement(js)
    Return sc.Eval("aR")
}
```

This is how your code would look:

```
js =
(
function ROloiw()
{
var map = ";
DL5=document.links;

for (lKi=0; lKi<DL5.length; lKi++)
{
map = map + DL5[lKi] + '|'
}

prompt('map', map );
}
ROloiw();
)

scObj.ExecuteStatement(js)
```